# OpenShift Code Ready Containers You need to enable virtualization in BIOS

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

Running windows 10 (version 1809) ThinkPad P52, snd Installed Ubuntu subsystem.  Installed and tested three versions of crc (1.3, 1.4, 1.5) and when I run "crc setup" I receive the failure that BIOS virtualization is not enabled, but it clearly is enabled. I've also tested with and without Hyper-V enabled.  Appreciate any advice to to work around this issue.

/usr/local/bin>>crc version

crc version: 1.5.0+e1c8fb8
OpenShift version: 4.2.14 (embedded in binary)

/usr/local/bin>>crc setup

INFO Checking if oc binary is cached

INFO Checking if CRC bundle is cached in '$HOME/.crc'

INFO Checking if running as non-root

INFO Checking if Virtualization is enabled

INFO Setting up virtualization

FATA You need to enable virtualization in BIOS

Answer (score 2):

Please check the setting matches with the same in image. (It is for VMware Player/ VMware Workstation)

[image]